# How to recover default background of domain computers

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I have set a default logon screen for computers on a WinSrv 2012 , but for some stupid reason have ticked the "Remove this item when no longer applied", and now I was re adjusting the policy and after deleting that rule all computers lost the defaultbackground.jpg file.

Now I want to put it back but no way it will go.

How can I force everyone to gather the file again?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved,
Problem was that I had a physical path on the origin file instead of a network path and the workstations were looking at they own installation instead on the domain.